# Mongoose, how to add a product to a order and validate the product

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my first nodejs project and I´m trying to build a simple online store for learning purposes. I really need some help with this one.

When i create a new order, i want to get the product details(title, price) based on the objectid passed in the request and add it to to products in order. Or this is not the right way to go?
Should i instead, also pass the title and price in the request and then somehow validate it?

The request looks like this:

```
[{   
    "_id": "641362674261f5c1fb2ef349",
    "quantity": 3
},{   
    "_id": "641362854261f5c1fb2ef34c",
    "quantity": 39
}
]
```

productModel.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'A product must have a title.'],
      unique: [true, 'A product must have a unique title.'],
    },
    desc: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'A product must have a description.'],
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, 'A product must have a price.'],
    },
  },
);

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

module.exports = Product;
```

orderModel.js

```
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  products: [
    {
      _id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product',
        required: [true, 'An order must belong to a product.'],
      },
      title: {
        type: String,
      },
      price: {
        type: Number,
        require: [true, 'A product must have a price.'],
      },
      quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'A product must have a quantity.'],
        default: 1,
      },
    },
  ],
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: [true, 'A order must have a User Id.'],
  },
  eta: {
    type: Number,
    default: function () {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (25 - 5 + 1) + 5);
    },
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
});
```

orderController.js

```
exports.createOrderCheckout = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const newOrder = await Order.create({ user: req.user.id, products: req.body });

  res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      newOrder,
    },
  });

});
```

Or this is bad idea?
Should i instead, also pass the title and price in the request and then somehow validate it?

Appreciate all the help i can get to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can fetch the products from the Product collection with the ObjectID that was given in the request body. It could be something like `Product.findById()` [Reference](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-findById)

Once you have validated that the passed in ObjectID points to products in the collection, then you can proceed with the `Order.create()` function.

Hopefully that's what you were asking? Apologies if I misunderstood your question.